# Dynamically creating objects in java when event(condition) occurs

Tags: java

one question again, I have still learned a lot from all of you, but now i need some advice again. First I will describe what I want to do. My goal is to create an area and fill it with points. Furthermore I want to split the area in small areas and to assign the right points to the new areas. Splitting should be performed only if event occurs, e.g. if the number of points in the area exceeds specific number k. Until now I have the following classes

```
public class Koord {

private int number;
private static int numberOfNodes = 0;
private int x;
private int y;

public Koord(int x, int y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.number = ++numberOfNodes;
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public int getNumber() {
    return number;
}
}
```

The Koord class is representing the points with coordinates and also static counter(just because i  need some names for my points).

```
import java.util.LinkedList;    

public class GeoArea {

private int[] area;

private LinkedList<Koord> areaContacts = new LinkedList<>();

/**
 * A empty GeoArea is created.
 */
public GeoArea() {
    area = new int[4];

}

/**
 * A GeoArea is created with the array of the parameters
 * 
 * @param x0
 * @param x1
 * @param y0
 * @param y1
 */
public GeoArea(int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1) {
    this.area = new int[4];
    this.area[0] = x0;
    this.area[1] = x1;
    this.area[2] = y0;
    this.area[3] = y1;

}

public void setArea(int x0, int x1, int y0, int y1) {
    area[0] = x0;
    area[1] = x1;
    area[2] = y0;
    area[3] = y1;
}

public int getX0() {
    return area[0];
}

public int getX1() {
    return area[1];
}

public int getY0() {
    return area[2];
}

public int getY1() {
    return area[3];
}

public LinkedList<Koord> getAreaContacts() {
    return areaContacts;
}

public void setAreaContacts(LinkedList<Koord> areaContacts) {
    this.areaContacts = areaContacts;
}

}
```

In the GeoArea class i have the coordinates of the area and also a linked list, where i want to save the points that belong to the area.

My third class is the class Display:

```
 import java.util.LinkedList;
 import java.util.Random;


 public class Display {
 public static void main(String args[]) {
     Random rand = new Random(); 


 GeoArea area1 = new GeoArea(0, 50, 0, 99);
 GeoArea area2 = new GeoArea(51, 99, 0, 99);

     LinkedList<Koord> ownArea = new LinkedList<Koord>();

      Koord point1 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));
      Koord point2 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));
      Koord point3 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));
      Koord point4 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));
      Koord point5 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));
      Koord point6 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));
      Koord point7 = new Koord(rand.nextInt(99), rand.nextInt(99));

      ownArea.add(point1);
      ownArea.add(point2);
      ownArea.add(point3);
      ownArea.add(point4);
      ownArea.add(point5);
      ownArea.add(point6);
      ownArea.add(point7);

      for(Koord c : ownArea) {
          if (area1.getX0() >= c.getX() || c.getX()< area1.getX1()) {
              area1.getAreaContacts().add(c);
            } else {
                area2.getAreaContacts().add(c);
            }
            System.out.println("x: " + c.getX() + " y: " + c.getY() +  " Element number" + c.getNumber());
      }

      for(Koord c : area1.getAreaContacts()) {

            System.out.println("Area 1  x: " + c.getX() + " y: " + c.getY() +  " Element number" + c.getNumber());
      }

      for(Koord c : area2.getAreaContacts()) {

            System.out.println("Area 2  x: " + c.getX() + " y: " + c.getY() +  " Element number" + c.getNumber());
      }


      System.out.println("List size:" + area1.getAreaContacts().size());
      System.out.println("List size:" + area2.getAreaContacts().size());
 }
}
```

As you can see, here i am creating some points with random coordinates. After that i am adding them to the area ownArea. After that i am going through the whole ownArea and comparing the coordinates with the coordinates of the two areas area1 and area2. So, now my goal is to check the size of ownArea every time I am adding new point(Koord) to it and if the size is greater than an integer k to split ownArea in n(e.g. 3) parts. The easiest way for me is to create n new areas and to copy the elements from ownArea to the new areas. But I want to do that dinamically, so if I change  "n" (number of areas to be splitted in) the number of the new areas is changed also. Can you give me some advices for doing this. I really want to learn something, so don't think that I need complete solution, hints and simple examples will be helpful too. Last - I am not very good at english, so my explanation are simple and also my grammatic is not the best, so feel free to propose any changes. Thank you very much.

Comment: Ok probably i have to remove the word "short". I wanted to make it short, but after that i have decided to explain it a little bit better.

Comment: Yes, I'd hate to read a long question.

Comment: I can understand you, but I think that in this case the long explanation is needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A couple of suggestions:

Since you want a variable number of areas, you could put the areas in a collection so that you can add more, instead of keeping them as instance variables. List for example. Use a map if you need to look up areas by name.

Then, when you want to replace an area, remove it from the collection and add the replacements.

It's probably easiest to divide an area into n sub-areas by splitting it only in one dimension (on y axis, for example). When you do that, be careful of handling any remainder after dividing by n.